# Preempting __del__ hmmm

Tags: python, class

I need to preempt `__del__` and I want to know what is the right way to do this.  Basically my question in code is this..

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger()
        self.log.debug("In init")
        self.closed = False

    def close(self):
        self.log.debug("Doing some magic")
        self.closed = True

    def __del__(self):
        if not self.closed:
            self.close()
        self.log.debug("In closing")

        # What should go here to properly do GC??
```

Is there any way to now call the standard GC features?

Thanks for reading!!

Steve

Comment: Preempt? Why? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__del__` isn't a true destructor. It is called before an object is destroyed to free any resources it is holding. It need not worry about freeing memory itself.

You can always call the parent class' `__del__`, too, if you are inheriting a class which may also have open resources.

Answer (score 3):

Please use the `with` statement for this.

See http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

> The with statement guarantees that if
>   the **enter**() method returns without
>   an error, then **exit**() will always
>   be called.

Rather than fool around with `__del__`, use `__exit__` of a context manager object.

Comment: @rh0dium: Did you read about the with statement and the context manager?  What questions did you have?

Comment: Only use the with statement if you know your code will not be used with versions of Python prior to 2.5, when it was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to call the GC manually then call gc.collect().